# Initialising an array of strings with unknown number and unknown length

Tags: c, arrays, string

So this is a real beginner question but I am completely lost. I am trying to generate an array of strings of the file names in a folder, so that I can then loop through each of the files and extract some information. Because the number of files and the length of the file names is not fixed I need to allocate the array dynamically. This is the code so far, it gets the file names from the folder but then errors when trying to assign the name to the array.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
size_t alen;
//input argument is folder path
char src[6], dest[512];
strcpy(src, "*.log");
strcpy(dest, argv[1]);
strcat(dest, src);
int fcount = 0;
char** lnames;

WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;

hFind = FindFirstFile(dest, &FindFileData);
    while (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

        alen = strlen(FindFileData.cFileName);
        *lnames = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*alen);
        lnames[fcount] = FindFileData.cFileName;
        fcount++;
        if (!FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData))
        {
            FindClose(hFind);
            hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }
return(0);
}
```

The error is "The variable 'lnames' is being used without being initialized". But isn't that what the malloc should be doing? One way forward I thought of using the same code to count the number of files and then doing:

```
char *lnames[fcount];
```

But the [] value needs to be  a constant which fcount wouldn't be so I'm quite stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'isn't that what the malloc should be doing?' - no.  You malloc is allcating space for the filename, but nothing is allocating/reallocating space for the pointers to the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your `malloc()` call initializes `*lnames`, not `lnames`. And in doing that, it uses the value of `lnames`, which indeed has not been initialized.

What you need extra, is to allocate some space for your `lnames` array. Every time you add a file name, it needs to become longer.
For efficiency reasons you would want to do that in batches, not every time, but this is a nice start:

Add a variable that counts how many names you have so far:

```
int numnames = 0;
```

near the top.

Change the declaration of `lnames` to initialize it:

```
char** lnames = NULL
```

and every time you're going to add a new name, do

```
numnames++;
lnames = realloc(lnames, numnames * sizeof (char *));
```

Instead of storing your `malloc()`ed string (don't cast the result of malloc!) in `*lnames`, use `lnames[numnames - 1]`.

You should also check for errors (`malloc()` and `realloc()` may fail), but this would be a good start.

I am deliberately not giving you a complete "perfect" edited version of your program, to leave some exercise for the reader (which is good for beginners ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Made the changes, had to add (**char) on the realloc. The code compiles and runs the problem now is that after the loop if I print the value of lnames[0] and lnames[1] they have the same value, the last file in the folder (hence last string in the loop), so it appears to be overwriting the entire array with each entry.

Comment: After some debugging the issue appears to be the 

FindFileData.cFileName

When FindNextFile is called the value in FindFileData.cFileName updates and does all the values in lnames. I tried dereferencing the FindFileData but that just outputs garbage. Again I'm a little stuck.

Comment: Ah, looking at your original code a bit further (note that I can't run it, since I don't use MSWindows), I see that although you reserve some actual space with the `malloc`, you don't actually use it! You immediately overwrite the pointer to your allocated memory with the value that is returned by `FindFirstFile()` or `FindNextFile()` (`FindFileData.cFileName`) . Likely each call re-uses the same memory to store the file name in. So you should copy the name using `strdup()`. Also, I see that you should `malloc()` 1 extra byte: for the terminating zero for the file name strings.

Comment: I also now see your `fcount` variable which serves pretty much the same purpose as my `numnames`. With some care you can merge them to single variable.

Comment: I notice a typo in my comment 2 places up: I meant `strcpy()`, not `strdup()`. The latter function combines the functionality of allocating memory and making a copy, so if you use it, you don't need a separate call to `malloc()` any more.

Comment: strcpy did the trick, strcpy(lnames[numnames -1],FindFileData.cFileName) is what I used.

Thanks for your help and thanks for teaching me a bit about pointers.